# spring boot app unable to detect truststore

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

When I tried to start my spring boot app, I specified following 3 VM arguments:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore.password=123456
```

I see the following 2 lines in the logs and my application failed to start with ssl error:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|17|restartedMain|2021-01-28 09:07:35.247 EST|TrustStoreManager.java:161|Inaccessible trust store: truststore.jks
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|17|restartedMain|2021-01-28 09:07:35.248 EST|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5\lib\security\cacerts
```

I have put my trustore.jks file in `src/main/resource` folder but somehow spring boot is unable to access/detect it, also I am on a corporate machine and can't add the server certificates to cacerts so that solution won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

for `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` you need to set the full path to the store /path/to/truststore.jks and also you need to set the type of store like this

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks
```